# Downloading image using Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I'm looping through a number of image uri's to download them locally.

This is the code I'm using:

```
const optionsImg = {
url: basePath,
   headers: {
       'User-Agent': 'request'
   }
};

let download = function(url, filename, callback) {
   optionsImg.url = url
   request.head(optionsImg, (err, res, body) => {
      console.log('content-type:', res.headers['content-type']);
      console.log('content-length:', res.headers['content-length']);

      request(optionsImg).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filename)).on('close', callback);
   });
};
```

But it's only ever saving the last image in the list. What I suspect is happening is it's trying to download async, and the fs.createWriteStream keeps being interrupted, till the list has finished. Therefore only downloading the last image successfully.

The console.logs do show different content-length.

How best to get round this issue? Thanks in advance.

Edit:
This is the loop code:

```
for (let x = 0; x < pics.length; x++) {
    download(pics[x], localPath + x + '.jpeg', function() {
        console.log('done');
    });
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer)?

Comment: Thanks for the response. That seems aim at multi part form submission, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Are you saving every file to a different filename?

Comment: Seems like you are overriding what you are saving

Comment: Yes, you want to get the images locally? Can you show the looping code? You might need to create promise for every file read and once you get the values use write stream.

Comment: Yes I am. I'm just calling them 1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg etc. But they are all the same image. The last on the list.

Comment: You can create multiple streams for read and pipe them to write stream. You should check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15315674/piping-multiple-file-streams-using-node-js/52113826).

Comment: Yeah. That looks like the very thing. Thanks dude.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the time `request.head` has finished—which, because it is a network request it might as well be "an eternity" as far as a computer is concerned—`optionsImg.url` will always have the same value because you keep re-using the same object.

Consider this:

```
const obj = { a: undefined };
for(let i = 0; i <= 3; i++) { 
  obj.a = i; 
  setTimeout(console.log, 100, obj);   
}
// will log {a:3} always
```

You'd fix the above problem by cloning the object:

```
const obj = { a: undefined };
for(let i = 0; i <= 3; i++) { 
  const obj2 = Object.assign({}, obj);
  obj2.a = i; 
  // or const obj2 = { ...obj, a: i };
  setTimeout(console.log, 100, obj2);   
}
// will log {a:0}, {a:1}, {a:2}, {a:3}
```

And some goes for your code:

```
let download = function(url, filename, callback) {
   const options = {
       ...optionsImg,
       url: url,
   }
   /* alternatively you can do:
   const options = Object.assign({}, optionsImg);
   options.url = url; */
   request.head(options, (err, res, body) => {
      console.log('content-type:', res.headers['content-type']);
      console.log('content-length:', res.headers['content-length']);

      request(options).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filename)).on('close', callback);
   });
};
```

`Object.assign` and `{...optionsImg}` do a shallow copy, so `headers` would still be re-used.

Now every time `download()` is called it and the `request()` calls it triggers will have 'its own' copy of the options object.

---

Edit: you don't need this for the stated problem in the OP, but should you also want to copy the headers object—perhaps you want to manipulate its value for every request—then you could do:

```
const options = {
  ...optionsImg,
  headers: { 
    ...optionsImg.headers,
    // as an example:
    'X-this-is-request-number': `${x} out of ${pics.length}`,
  },
  url: url,
};
```

You could also search for a recursive object cloning utility; there are many.