# stream a chain of video files using nodejs

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to stream multiple files as one stream using nodejs. But it only streams the first one. When the range reaches the second file, streaming get stuck and browser again asks for the previous range.

```
const streamData = async () => {

            const files = fs.readdirSync(`storage/recordings/tmp/${id}`);

            // create array of file info
            let fileSize = 0;
            filesObj = files.map(file => {                    
                let size = fs.statSync(`storage/recordings/tmp/${id}/` + file).size;
                fileSize += size;
                return {
                    path: `storage/recordings/tmp/${id}/` + file,
                    size: size,
                    start: fileSize - size,
                    end: fileSize
                }
            })
            
            const range = req.headers.range
            console.log('range',range);

            const CHUNK_SIZE = 10 ** 6;
            const parts = range ? range.replace(/bytes=/, "").split("-") : ['0','']
            const start = parseInt(parts[0], 10)
            // console.log('filesObj',filesObj);
            // console.log('start',start);

            // console.log(filesObj);
            let selectIndex = filesObj.findIndex(i => i.start <= start && i.end > start)
            let currentFile = filesObj[selectIndex];
            let prevFile = selectIndex > 0 ? filesObj[selectIndex-1] : null;
            let end = Math.min(start + CHUNK_SIZE, currentFile.end);

            // console.log('end',end);
            // console.log(fileSize);
            // const chunksize = (end - start)
            
            let s = start;
            let e = end;
            filesObj.slice(0,selectIndex).forEach((item) => {
                 s -= item.size;
                e -= item.size;
            });

            // console.log('s',s);
            // console.log('e',e);
            // console.log('filesize',fileSize);
            // console.log('prevFile',prevFile);
            // console.log('currentFile',currentFile);

            const stream = fs.createReadStream(currentFile.path, {
                start:s,
                end:e
            });

            const head = {
                'Content-Range': `bytes ${start}-${end}/${fileSize}`,
                'Accept-Ranges': 'bytes',
                'Content-Length': CHUNK_SIZE,
                'Content-Type': 'video/webm',
            }
            res.writeHead(206, head);

            // stream.pipe(res);
            stream.on('data', (data) => {
                res.write(data);
            })
            stream.on('end', (data) => {
                res.end(data);
            })
        }

        streamData();
```

What i did in code:

1. first get the array of video files
2. sum the size of all files
3. create a list of all files and where their byte start and end
4. get the range from header and select the correct file
5. stream the file with proper start and end

I did what mentioned in  [Piping multiple file streams using Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15315674/piping-multiple-file-streams-using-node-js) using multi stream:
By the help of following code it can not be played at browser. It is still only plays the first one and sometimes stuck at the first one too. But Chrome can play the videos sometimes.

```
 const files = fs.readdirSync(`storage/recordings/tmp/${id}`);

            let streams = [];
            files.forEach((i) => {
                streams.push(fs.createReadStream(`storage/recordings/tmp/${id}/${i}`))
            })

            // This will stuck too
            // streams.forEach(stream => {
            //     stream.pipe(res);
            // })

            // if the linked opened by firefox it will only play the first video and if opened by chrome it will play the rest.
// if the source files are different, it it will work on chrome. but if the files are exactly the same it only pipe the first one
                new MultiStream(streams).pipe(res);
```

do you have any idea?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Piping multiple file streams using Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15315674/piping-multiple-file-streams-using-node-js)

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial it somehow works for Chrome but not on Firefox. For some reason does not work in chrome too if files are the same.

Comment: nodejs is backend. You only need to ensure it streams. If it works in one browser but not the other, then you need to look at your frontend stack.

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial well in my idea a standard stream should work on most native video players provided by most browsers. And I am only using the default player of browser, no client java-script is written. Not to mention that, it does not always express the same behavior in all cases. You are only a refresh away to face the bug.  The lucky successful stream of certain chain of files on chrome that might happen, does not mean it is really a good stream at first place.

Comment: Not all browser are the same, and "face the bug" is not enough to illustrate the problem. You should open a new question to illustrate what is the bug and how the bug happen in order to get an answer you want.

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial I already mentioned the problem. It only plays the first video, and sometimes can not even play the first one. My mistake was I mentioned other browsers. Chrome doesn't work either. It is only sometimes lucky! I don't believe it is font-end issue. I have been working by different browsers and video streaming and haven't seen this behavior. and tested with regular one file streaming and they are fine. There is something wrong with stream that can not complete the stream and makes the browser think the video is ended. That's why my question is "How to stream.." not "How to play".